# Datepicker hilight on hover multiple dates up to 24

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ulitka911/KQrs5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<label > How Long </label> 
    <select id="weeks">
      <option value="1">1 Week</option>
      <option value="2">2 Weeks</option>
      <option value="3">3 Weeks</option>
      <option value="4">4 Weeks</option>
    </select> 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">

<script>
$(function() {
var weeks;
var daysInWeek = 7;
var totalDays;
weeks = $("#weeks").val();
totalDays = weeks * daysInWeek;

$(function() {
        $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                if(this.id == 'from'){
                  var dateMin = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
                  var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); 
                  var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + totalDays); 
                  //$('#to').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);
                  //$('#to').datepicker("option","maxDate",rMax);  
$('#to').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(rMax)));                    
                }

            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so my challenge is :

1. I have option where costumer can choose from 1 to 4 weeks. 
   My total days is always stay 7 it does not calculated properly. I understand that value is have to be "refreshed"when selected, but I don't know ajax and I don't want to refresh entire page to get proper calculation(I am not even sure if what I wrote is correct way do do it.)
2. I have been trying to research about highlighting dates on hover here is example
   http://jsfiddle.net/eFzG4/, but it highlights a row of week,and I am trying to highlight the number of days between 7 to 28, I am not even sure if it is possible to highlight dates on 2 months.

Thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: perhaps Can you make your challenge 2 be clear, so it is easy to answer

Comment: Sorry about not good explanation. I will try with example lets say costumer selected 1 week of staying it is 7 days so when costumer will hover he's cursor over lets say number 14 the number 14,15,16,17,18,19,20 will be highlighted instead of as it is right now 12,13,14,15,16,17,18 . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this function to be added in your code

```
$("#weeks").on("change",function(){
   totalDays = $("#weeks").val() * daysInWeek;
   alert(totalDays)
})
```

**Edit**: [Please take a look at this](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html)

Comment: that works for my first problem thank you for your tie and fast respond.